# why doesn't this code work with a static method in a class?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

```
namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    class Program
    {
        class MyClass
        {
            public int age;
            public string name;

            public static MyClass createobj() {

                MyClass returnit = new MyClass();
                returnit.age = 45;
                returnit.name = "Homer Simpson";
                return returnit;

            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
           MyClass homer =  createobj();

           Console.WriteLine(homer.age);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the error message:

`The name 'createobj' does not exist in the current context`

Why am i receiving this error message even though I have made the createobj() method static?
I tried `MyClass homer = MyClass.createobj();` which did not return any errors and the program ran fine? why cant i just use `MyClass homer = createobj();`?

Comment: Because you aren't in that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined the function `createobj()` within the `MyClass` class. `Main()`, however, does not belong to that class, but to the Program. In order to call a static method you need to state to which class it belongs, so the call should be `MyClass homer = MyClass.createobj()`. That being said, this could in this simple case be just as easily done with the class' constructor, that is:

```
MyClass homer = new MyClass()
```

And then you define the constructor within the MyClass class as:

```
class MyClass
{
  //...
  public MyClass()
  {
    age = 45;
    name = "Homer";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CreateObj is a method on MyClass.

Your main method is outside MyClass.

Therefore, you must use **MyClass.CreateObj();**